# How to concatenate a "%" to an input?

Tags: python, calculator

Below is a copy of my simple tip calculator:

```
bill_total = float(input("What is your total?\n"))

people_total = float(input("How many people are splitting the bill?\n"))

tip_percent = float(input("What percent tip would you like to leave?\n"))

total = (bill_total + (int(bill_total*(tip_percent/100))))/(people_total)

print("Everyone should leave about $" +'{:.2f}'.format(round(total, 2)))
```

How would I go about concatenating a "%" sign to the end of the user's input so that result shows a percentage sign without them having to type the actual sign?

i.e:
"What percent tip would you like to leave?"
20%

Comment: "How would I go about concatenating a "%" sign to the end of the user's input" Well, how *are* you *already* going about concatenating the user's input to the end of the message `"Everyone should leave about $"`?

Answer (score 1):

The entire code is fine, except for the print statement.

You don't need to add a + symbol, just keep everything in the strings.

When you are using {:.2f}, you don't need to use round function and vice versa.

```
print("Everyone should leave about $ {:.2f}%".format(total))
```